# Rails: cannot load such file -- arel/factory_methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I am new to Rails and am setting up this [prelauncher](https://github.com/Techofficer/prelauncher) project.  When I run `bundle exec rake db:create db:schema:load db:seed` to setup the database I receive the following error and trace:

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- arel/factory_methods
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/arel-6.0.1/lib/arel.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/delayed_job_active_record-4.0.3/lib/delayed_job_active_record.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
/Users/Me/Desktop/prelauncher/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Me/Desktop/prelauncher/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/Users/Me/Desktop/prelauncher/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
```

I've cleaned my gems multiple times and rerun `bundle install` which returns success.  PostgreSQL is installed via brew (checked with `psql --list`).

Comment: The current Rails version is 4.2.5. Have you tried pinning that in the Gemfile?

Comment: If you're new to Rails that would be `gem 'rails',  '>=4.2.5'` in the Gemfile.

Comment: It was at 4.2.1.  I changed it to 4.2.5, updated the gems and have gotten past the error!

Comment: Cool! Pay it forward :-)